# How to repeat same values in mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, loops

I'm trying to repeat N times an array with a FOR loop, but I've been stuck in the last array that contains more elements. This is my code so far:

```
function data() {
    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++) {
        $magnitud = array('nombre' => 'medidor');
        for ($j = 1 ; $j <= 5 ; $j++) {
            $magnitude['magnitude'.$i] = array('date' => $date, 'value' => mt_rand(1,200));;  
        }
    }
    return $magnitude;
}

for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++) { 
    $center->insertOne(['meter' => 'meter'.$i, 'data' => data()]);
}
```

I need to repeat 5 times the values of the array that contains the date and a value.

```
array('date' => $date, 'value' => mt_rand(1,200));
```

Something like this:

```
Date: 05/03/2015
Value: 25
Date: 10/12/2012
Value: 45
Date: 15/06/2005
Value: 67
Date: 26/05/2009
Value: 78
.
.
.
```

I've tried it in many ways, but I haven't achieved. Someone who lend me a hand to how to repeat N times that array?

Just in case you haven't got any idea about my question, I attach this picture which is what I get in Robo3T (Visual Manager)

[image]

EDIT: To explain myself better, this is the JSON that I'm trying to get.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ab0c29db57dce17e0002bc0"),
"meter" : "meter1",
"data" : {
    "magnitude1" : {
        "date" : "20/10/2015 21:57:05",
        "value" : 192,
        "date" : "13/12/2015 22:51:15",
        "value" : 85,
        "date" : "15/05/2016 05:21:06",
        "value" : 65,
        "date" : "28/06/2017 15:32:26",
        "value" : 72,
        "date" : "02/11/2017 18:15:34",
        "value" : 12,
    },
    "magnitude2" : {
        "date" : "15/12/2009 15:21:32",
        "value" : 45,
        "date" : "12/05/2013 16:45:07",
        "value" : 96,
        "date" : "21/02/2015 03:06:12",
        "value" : 85,
        "date" : "15/08/2015 14:05:22",
        "value" : 78,
        "date" : "05/01/2017 21:12:32",
        "value" : 198,
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to have 5 sub arrays of the `magnitude` array, so do it like this

```
function data() {
    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++) {
        for ($j = 1 ; $j <= 5 ; $j++) {
            $magnitude['magnitude'.$i][] = array('date' => $date, 'value' => mt_rand(1,200));;  
        }
    }
    return $magnitude;
}
```

Not the use of `[]` in this line `$magnitude['magnitude'.$i][]` which will create a new sub occurrence within `$magnitude['magnitude'.$i]` each time round the inner loop

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your code is creating a new sub-document for each new file. Probably, I haven't explained myself well. Basically what I want is repeat 5 (or more) times the array of `data` and `value` inside the document `magnitude`.

Comment: So the only way to repeat anything is to place it in an array subordinate to the magnitude array

Comment: Honestly I am not now sure what you are trying to do. Can you edit the question and give me a clue what you want the result to look like please

Comment: Ok. Is already edited with the json I'm trying to get. I hope it helps you.

Comment: But thats INVALID JSON. Look closer, you are asking to create multiple properties of an object with the same name. Thats not going to work

Comment: You can only have ONE  `magniture1.date` not 5 hence I put that data into an array

Comment: alright, I thought I could repeat same data in the same document. So, that's what I wanted to know. Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the values are always overwrited as the key is never changed in the second loop. You can simplify it like this:

```
function data()
{
    $value = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 250 ; $i++) {
        $value = $i % 5 === 0 ? mt_rand(1, 200) : $value;
        $magnitude['magnitude' . ($i + 1)] = array('date' => $date, 'value' => $value);
    }

    return $magnitude;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your code is repeating the same 'value' all the time and also, what I want is repeat 5 (or more) times the array of `data` and `value` inside the document of `magnitude`. However, your loop it's interesting.

Comment: And yes, I'm overwriting the values. I didn't notice that.